# How to filter Django object to get top X number of objects with highest property value

Tags: python, django, class

So I have a class called Hero with 150 objects. Each object has a property Winrate. I want to get the top 12 heros based on winrate.

```
class Hero(models.Model):

    hero_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = 'Dota 2 Hero') 
    hero_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hero_id)
    def get_winrate(self):
        wins = len(Match.objects.filter(heros_won = Hero.objects.get(hero_id = self.hero_id)))
        losses = len(Match.objects.filter(heros_lost  = Hero.objects.get(hero_id = self.hero_id)))
        if wins + losses != 0:
            return round((wins / (wins + losses)),2)
        else:
            return 0 
    winrate = property(get_winrate)
```

I tried alot of filters but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I suggest you add the win rate as a property of your model. Then you can use the sorted query to get what you want. With what you have right now, you have to compute this win rate using multiple queries into the database for each object, on all of the rows in the table, to get the top twelve.

Comment: I have winrate as property dont I?  
```winrate = property(get_winrate)```

Comment: Does doing that allow you to use a sorted query on the `winrate` field?

Answer (score 1):

I would make `winrate` an **attribute** of your Hero **class** as following.

```
class Hero(models.Model):

    hero_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = 'Dota 2 Hero') 
    hero_id = models.IntegerField()
    winrate = models.IntegerField()

    def _get_winrate(self):
        wins = len(Match.objects.filter(heros_won = Hero.objects.get(hero_id = self.hero_id)))
        losses = len(Match.objects.filter(heros_lost  = Hero.objects.get(hero_id = self.hero_id)))
        if wins + losses != 0:
            return round((wins / (wins + losses)),2)
        else:
            return 0 

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        self.winrate = self._getwinrate()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you'll be able to order your request.

```
super_heroes = Hero.objects.order_by('-winrate')[:12]
```

EDIT: you shouldn't use **len()** on a queryset but **count()** like this:

```
wins = Match.objects.filter(heros_won=self.pk).count()
```

Why don't you use the natural primary key instead of this `hero_id`?

Comment: What does `
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        self.winrate = self._getwinrate()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)` do here?

Comment: It's quite obvious. Every time you save your instance, it updates your instance each time you save it. BTW I've edited my post.